# why am I getting a very high test accuracy even when i test my dataset with a single feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am writing a small program and I am training a random forest to predict a binary value. My dataset has around 20,000 entries and each entry has 25 features(continuous and categorical) with a binary target value to predict.
I am getting over 99% test accuracy which is surprisingly high. I tried to reduce the number of my features, even with two features I am still getting such high accuracy. I just want to make sure I am not doing anything wrong in my code, such as the training set leaking into my test set.
Here is the code snippet

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv')
data = data.drop_duplicates()
#spliting data
X = data.drop('label', axis=1)
y = data['label']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#preproccessing the dataset by one hot encoding
l1 = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
l1.fit(X_train)
X_train = l1.transform(X_train)
X_test = l1.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train.to_numpy())

#evaluation
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

additionally, I forgot to add that my dataset is balanced and precision and recall scores are 100% !

Comment: How balanced are your target values in the dataset?

Comment: Can you make a toy data set that can be defined within the code snippet, and add the imports to make a code snippet that anybody else could run?

Comment: Probably not the answer but as advice, you can change the "random_state=0". With zero random_state reproduces the same output every time.

Comment: @AkinGunduz I changed it to 20.  does that mean my accuracy may change every time?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a big dataset. How balanced is your dataset? It might be the case your test split is filled mostly with the entries of one label and failed every time the entry was from the other label. Therefore, i would say accuracy is not a good measure to rely on in here.

Have a look at this:
[Difference of model accuracy and performance](https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-accuracy-is-not-enough-more-performance-measures-you-can-use/)

Have a look at your confusion matrix and inspect your splits.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I forgot to add that my dataset is almost balanced. however yes apparently my test set consisted of the same labels, but even after I shuffled the dataset, again I received a quite high accuracy. Also, I am getting a 1.0 and 0.99 for my precision and recall scores respectively.

Comment: @MaryamIsakhani, I recommend to inspect your model further. For example, calculate your feature importance or permutation importance to see the impact of your features on the performance of the model [useful link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html). Or simply try a different model and see how the behavior changes.